# Subclassing generic type

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to do something like this but it does not work:

```
class Foo<T: UIViewController>: T {}
```

so Foo is a subclass of T which must be at least UIViewController.

and then

```
let obj = Foo<UIViewControllerSubclass>()
```

but I get the following compiler error:

Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'T'

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: but why? the compiler knows that T is at least a UIViewController instance, is not it?

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve ? If you just want to add some decorations to the UIViewControllerSubclass, why don't declare Foo as a protocol ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have a framework where Foo subclasses UIViewController. In the main project I have class Bar which also subclasses UIViewController. Now I need to have the stuff from Bar into Foo as well. If I can define Foo as generic class that excepts T as super class type (which subclasses UIViewController) I can instantiate Foo as following : let obj = Foo<Bar>(). So I need to "extend" Foo by putting a layer between UIViewController and Foo, without changing the framework to much.

Comment: Both Foo & Bar override UIViewController methods, otherwise I would use protocols.